# docker-php-ext-install - why always using dev?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to install the php-gd extension via `docker-php-ext-install` and I found a lot of answers about this.

But my question is: when I apt-get install php5-gd inside the docker-container I get packages without `-dev` and I dont like using always dev. But if I add just the dependencies without the dev-ending (the ones it showed me with apt-get install inside the container) it is not working.

So: Why I have to use `-dev` dependencies?